# Thousand Pillars Mantap in Ranganatha temple, Sri Rangam

Tags: history, temple, ranganatha

In Srirangam Ranganathaswamy temple there is a 1000 pillared mantap. It is said that a Chola king built this overnight as per the order of the God. In total how many pillars are there and any scripture reference supporting that it has been built overnight? Please cascade.

Comment: Can you edit titles of your questions? Some are vague. Some people just skip if they see one word titles in questions.

Comment: That means they do not have patience to see one line itself---how will they view a full lengthy sentence as title? They will skip and because of this many questions are unanswered.

Comment: It's just a suggestion: You can change your title to something like" Did Chola King build 1000 pillar mandapam overnight at command of Lord Ranganatha?" or something else.  Users will get essence of question.

Comment: It is a punch title and the viewers will be kindled to see the body of the question--Hence that type---thanks for your suggestion--But I cannot change my way. All 5 fingers are not equal.